# get request value in middleware laravel in handle function

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {  

    $login = new LoginController();

    dd(Input::get('pass'));
    if ($login->login_check()) {
        if ($this->is_logged_in()) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return new RedirectResponse(url('/auth/login'));
        }
    }

    //return $next($request);
}
```

This is my custom middleware. I want to get request value in handle function. I want to pass input field value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change Input::get('pass') to

```
Request::input('pass');
```

and remember to import the Request facade using a use Request; statement

Comment: i have use  Request facade yet geting null value

Comment: Oh, ok then try to change `handle($request, Closure $next) {` to `handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {` I'm not sure, just try it.

Comment: given error -: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Middleware\CustomeMiddleware::handle() must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given

Comment: Ok, remove that `Request` and also change `Input::get('pass')` to `$request->pass`

Comment: sorry yaar  not yet :(